# Are there any embedded video/media field modules which integrate with Rules?

Tags: rules

I'm trying to set up some Rules conditions which deal with whether or not a user has added a YouTube URL into a media field for a node. The idea is to use a Media type module to embed the YouTube video into the forum post. But I want a specific Rule to fire if the user saves their forum post without adding a YouTube video URL to that custom field.

However, I can't seem to find a module like Media or Video Embed Field, or Embedded Media field which expose that field entity to Rules.

Comment: what do you want the rule to do?

Comment: I want to check to see if a user had actually entered anything into the embedded video field, by running a condition for "NOT field is empty".

If the field has been utilized, I want to run an action performing an update on the node author's account, like award userpoints.

I run into problems when I try to set the condition for "field is empty". The rules framework doesn't see the entity though.

Comment: you can assign userpoints with one line of code as well

Comment: We're trying to do as much as possible with well maintained contrib or core modules. It may be a pipe dream, but it's a goal.

Comment: that's a good practice. Personally, I like to keep the system as simple as possible. If I can add a functionality with 5 lines of codes I rather do that than install a module. The Userpoints API doc is here if you want to give that a try: http://drupal.org/node/206558

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hook_form_alter() to check if a youtube video has been added. Then run [rules_invoke_event()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.module/function/rules_invoke_event/7) to trigger the rule.

Btw, I personally like the Video Embed Field module.

Comment: Yeah, it appears that any of the media modules which generate a custom field of some sort for the purposes of storing a YouTube like video URL, would need to be modified to expose their entity metadata to the Entity API. As indicated here I believe: http://drupal.org/node/878880

unfortunately, that is beyond my skill or capacity to manage at this juncture.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't perused them all, but Johan Falk posted a new bunch of Rules videos just before Drupalcon Denver.  You may find a solution within them:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BunFdtCTfK0&feature=results_main&playnext=1&list=PL84B6FFA4F7ACAD57
Best of luck!
Susan